# python compiler package explain

Tags: python, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I searched hard, but could hardly find any information on how to use the python compiler package (https://docs.python.org/2/library/compiler.html) and how to create a Visitor class that can be feed into the compiler.walk(https://docs.python.org/2/library/compiler.html#compiler.walk) method.

Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What part of the "[Using Visitors to Walk ASTs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/compiler.html#module-compiler.visitor)" gave you trouble?

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase In the compiler.visitor.walk() method, it accepts 2 paramenters, tree and visitor. What are those? And how can i obtain those?

Comment: Do note that, as the linked documentation states, the `compiler` package is deprecated. You should probably be using the `ast` package instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a visitor class by defining a subclass of `compiler.visitor.ASTVisitor` and then defining a method `visitXXX` for each type of node that you want your visitor to handle (where `XXX` is the name of the node type - the possible types of nodes are listed in the table in the documentation you linked).

Any such method will take one argument (two if you count `self`), which will be the node object representing the visited node. The attributes available on such an object are also listed in the table. If you want the visitor to proceed further into the tree, you should call `visit` on each child node of the node.

> In the compiler.visitor.walk() method, it accepts 2 paramenters, tree and visitor. What are those?

`tree` is the AST that you want to process and `visitor` is an instance of the visitor class that you created to process that AST.

> And how can i obtain those?

You obtain the AST by calling `compiler.parse` on some Python source code and you obtain the visitor by writing a visitor class and creating an instance of it.

Here's an example using a visitor that simply counts the number of addition operators in a piece of Python code:

```
import compiler

class PlusCounter(compiler.visitor.ASTVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def visitAdd(self, node):
        self.count += 1
        self.visit(node.left)
        self.visit(node.right)

plus_counter = PlusCounter()
compiler.walk(compiler.parse("1 + 2 * (3 + 4)"), plus_counter)
print(plus_counter.count)
```

---

And here's the same example using the non-deprecated `ast` package, which works basically the same way, but has a slightly different AST structure. Unlike the above code, this one will actually work in Python 3:

```
import ast

class PlusCounter(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pluses = 0

    def visit_Add(self, node):
        # We don't need to visit any child nodes here because in the ast package
        # the AST is structured slightly differently and Add is merely a child
        # node of the BinOp node, which holds the operands. So Add itself has
        # no children that need to be visited
        self.pluses += 1

plus_counter = PlusCounter()
plus_counter.visit(ast.parse("1 + 2 * (3 + 4)"))
print(plus_counter.pluses)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the `compiler` package is deprecated, you should probably also take a look at the [`ast` package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html).

Good docs on the Python `ast` can be found in "[Green Tree Snakes - The Missing Python AST docs](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)".
A very extensive example of it's use is [Transcrypt's `Generator` class](https://github.com/JdeH/Transcrypt/tree/1dd2380441fa371e33e3f272f3911fb2743baa98/transcrypt/modules/org/transcrypt/compiler.py#L434).